# How can I make my REGEX general?

Tags: regex

These are my inputs

```
Cream & Sugar > Chocolates > Cakes & Cherries
Cream & Sugar > Chocolates > Cakes & Cherries > Ice > Cold Coffee
```

This is my regex

```
(([A-Z][a-z]+)\s&\s([A-Z][a-z]+)).*
```

I want my output to capture the third group from right

```
one=Cream & Sugar
one=Cakes & Cherries
```

My regex works for the first input but not the second input. The regex should match the entire input and the first group should capture the third group from right always with no space in the end. I am using The Regex Coach tool.

Comment: Please try to be more specific in your question, showing desired match ("`the entire input`"), not only captures, and perhaps with some emphasis on the condition that you want the third group **from the right**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegexCouch does not support named groups, and lookbehinds, is such case you can use:

```
.*(?:^|\>\s)([^>]+)(?=(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$).*
```

to match whole line with desired output captured in group 1.

---

If you use regex flavour supporting lookarounds, you can use:

```
(?m)(?<=^|\>\s)(?<one>[^>]+)(?=(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nE9gY2/4)

- `(?m)` - multiline mode,
- `(?<=^|\>\s)` - positive lookbehind for beginnig of a line, or `>`
- `(?<one>[^>]+)` - matching selected words
- `(?=(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$)` - positive look ahed for two other items between `>` and `>` or end of a line,

Without lookarounds:

```
(?m)(?:^|\>\s)(?<one>[^>]+)(?:(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nE9gY2/3)

desired output is captured in group `<one>`

Both regexes gives (direct or by capturing groups) output:

```
Cream & Sugar
Cakes & Cherries
```

Comment: the solution does not work with the regex coach tool :( any ideas to make it regex coach compatible? thanks.

Comment: @Meow try with `(?m)(?:^|\>\s)([^>]+)(?=(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$)`, use `g` flags

Comment: @m.cekiera- The above solution is capturing the desired groups perfectly. But it is not matching the entire input string. Any suggestions to match the entire string with your solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Meow this should work: `.*(?:^|\>\s)([^>]+)(?=(?:\s(?:^|\>)[^>]+){2}$).*` with `m` mode - match entire line, and desired values into group 1

Comment: @m.cekiera- WOW! perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to match empty inputs you can use:

```
word = [A-Z][a-z]+
group = (word)((\s>\s)(word))*
regex = (group)(\s&\s(group)).*
```

i.e. first group is obligatory = `(group)` and then `(space)&(space)(group)` zero or more times. And the same for `> (word)`: it is optional.

Comment: Your regex captures just Cream for the first input and the second inputs. I need to capture  Cream & Sugar and Cakes & Cherries respectively. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the > part. I have just edited my answer to deal with it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ERE with sed:

```
$ s=$(printf 'Cream & Sugar > Chocolates > Cakes & Cherries\nCream & Sugar > Chocolates > Cakes & Cherries > Ice > Cold Coffee\n')
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/(.*> )?([^>]+)(>[^>]+){2}$/\2/'
Cream & Sugar
Cakes & Cherries
```

Or BRE if you need to use older tools:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/\(.*> \)\{0,\}\([^>][^>]*\)\(>[^>][^>]*\)\{2\}$/\2/'
Cream & Sugar
Cakes & Cherries
```

Note that I'm testing this in OSX; your sed may use other options for ERE.

These solutions simply use `>` as a delimiter, which means that you might be better off using something other than regex to parse this.

```
$ echo "$s" | awk -F' *> *' '{print $(NF-2)}'
Cream & Sugar
Cakes & Cherries
```

Comment: @ghoti- I am using regex coach tool, cannot do ERE with sed. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what "regex coach tool" is, but sed's "s" command searches on a regular expression and prints results based on recognized patterns. Whatever tool you are using can undoubtedly understand ERE.